# Jenkins shows error after successful project build creating

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, sonarqube

Jenkins shows error after build successfull. I have integrated sonarQube for code analysis.
I searched a lot but i not found any solution. waiting for help :)

```
RROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "C:\.jenkins\jobs\Hello\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:107)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.access$000(SvnBlameCommand.java:45)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand$1.call(SvnBlameCommand.java:91)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand$1.call(SvnBlameCommand.java:88)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "C:\.jenkins\jobs\Hello\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.execute(SvnBlameCommand.java:125)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:104)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:189)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the key bit:

> Cannot run program "svn"

The analysis is trying to query your SCM (apparently Subversion) for commit data on the files. It's not finding `svn` in $PATH to run, and that's causing analysis to fail.

Your options are to make `svn` available (preferable), or to configure the project on the server side to skip this part of the analysis.

If the project hasn't yet been created, you'll need to [provision](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Provisioning+Projects) it. Then use the project-level Administration menu: **Administration > General Settings > SCM** and set **Disable the SCM Sensor** to `true`.